# Not showing any images from URL

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to fetch images from my hosting, that contains link of my images. But when I trying to load it with glide it's not showing anything.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Myholder myholder=(Myholder) holder;
        DataFood current=data.get(position);
        myholder.textFoodname.setText(current.foodName);
        myholder.textPrice.setText("Rp. " + current.price);
        myholder.textId.setText(String.valueOf(current.foodId));


        Glide.with(context).load("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + current.foodImage).into(myholder.ivFood);
    }
```

Comment: Check your internet permission in Android Manifest.

Comment: already set, it can show any item, except the image

Comment: Make sure that there is something in the final url. If you put this ("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + current.foodImage) in your browser, does it show the image ?

Comment: Check image url in browser. Log it first `Log.d("IMAGE_URL", "http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + current.foodImage);`

Comment: @bogdanN it show the index of my picture

Comment: But you should get the name of image itself; not the index. Resolve this and you'll have your images in recyclerview.

Comment: make sure that image url ("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/"+ current.foodImage) having an image in server.

Comment: example: kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/martabak.jpg thats one of my image path

Comment: @eugeneek when i try the log.d it shows ic.launcher

Comment: Check the URL again. I think there should be some timestamp there.

Comment: your server do not have `ic.launcher` that's why it is not loading the image. It should be inside `pic` folder.

Comment: For URL kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/martabak.jpg must be `current.foodImage == martabak.jpg`

Comment: @eugeneek so i have to create it one by one?

Comment: @Fawwaz then try `Glide.with(myholder.ivFood.getContext()).load("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/mart‌​abak.jpg").into(myho‌​lder.ivFood);` it will work.

Comment: Glide.with(context).load("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/mart‌​abak.jpg").into(myho‌​lder.ivFood); i already tried this, but its still not showing anything

Comment: @Fawwaz you forgot adding `http://`

Comment: @AnandSingh already sir, but the problem is same

Comment: @Fawwaz try my edited answer i hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something! Can you try this option? I can help you, let me know if this works! :) have a nice day!

```
String url="http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + current.foodImage;
```

**or  you can try first this option :**

```
String urlImage="http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/martabak.jpg";

 Glide.with(context).load(urlImage).asBitmap().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(myholder.ivFood) {
            @Override
            protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                RoundedBitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable =
                        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                myholder.ivFood.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
            }
        });
```